# python split time variable into date and time

Tags: python

I have data frame which contains col like that

```
df['time']

2012-11-28 07:01:05

2012-11-28 07:01:05

2012-11-28 07:03:45

2012-11-28 07:06:02

2012-11-28 07:10:05

2012-11-28 07:12:04

2012-11-28 07:13:01
```

I want to split it into two **datetime** col

one for the date (2012-11-28) and the secound for the time (07:13:01)

so I did like that:

`df['date']=df['time'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime(x.year,x.month,x.day))`- work ok!

however when I type

```
df['date']=df['time'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime(x.hour,x.minute,x.second))
```

I got error - `ValueError: day is out of range for month`

I have no idea what to do

Comment: in df['time'] is every entry a datetime object?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because for the second `map` function call, you are creating `datetime` objects with hour, min, sec arguments. However, the first 3 arguments should be year, month, day. So, instead of the month, it is getting a minute value which is greater than 12.

Assuming your `df['time']` has `datetime` objects, you want to do something like this:

```
dates = map(lambda x: x.date(), df['time']) # get all dates
times = map(lambda x: x.time(), df['time']) # get all times
```

To get string representations:

```
dates = map(lambda x: str(x.date()), df['time']) # get all dates
times = map(lambda x: str(x.time()), df['time']) # get all times
```

Comment: thank u for your reply,
but than the tipe is time and not datetime
so u can't do time calculation for example
df.ix[1.'date']-df.ix[2.'date'] which i wan to do

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

base = datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 28, 7,1,5)
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(minutes=x) for x in range(0, 7)]
dates = [ dt.date() for dt in date_list]
times = [ dt.time() for dt in date_list]
for _date, _time in zip(dates, times):
    print('date=', _date, 'time=', _time)

date= 2012-11-28 time= 07:01:05
date= 2012-11-28 time= 07:00:05
date= 2012-11-28 time= 06:59:05
date= 2012-11-28 time= 06:58:05
date= 2012-11-28 time= 06:57:05
date= 2012-11-28 time= 06:56:05
date= 2012-11-28 time= 06:55:05
```